# Box around continued fraction

Tags: formatting, equations, boxes, fractions

Thanks for stopping by to help with my question.  I'm trying to mimic what my professor did in our notes, putting a box around a specific portion of a continued fraction, shown below:

[image: Continued fraction box]

Here's the LaTex code I was trying to use for the continued fraction itself (sorry, I don't know how to format it so it looks nice like other questions I've seen on here):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$X:=\cfrac{1}{a+\cfrac{1}{a+\cfrac{1}{a+\cfrac{1}{a+\cfrac{1}{a+\cdots}}}}}$$
\end{document}
```

Any help you might be able to provide would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use `\boxed`n and don't use `$$ … $$`, which is plain TeX code and produces bad spacing. Use `[ … \]` instead for unnumbered display formulae. Also with `:=`, the colon  is not centred on the maths axis. Prefer  `\coloneqq` instead, which is defined in `mathtools`, an extension of `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[ X\coloneqq\cfrac{1}{a+\boxed{\cfrac{1}{a+\cfrac{1}{a+\cfrac{1}{a+\cfrac{1}{a+ ⋯ }}}}}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Bernard!  I appreciate your help and assistance in formatting my question.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help!